# Inverses of Multivariable Functions from R^m to R^n

Tags: analysis, inverse

I was reading about Riemann Sphere and I found out that from the system:
$$ u(x,y) = x/(x^2+y^2+1) \\
  v(x,y) = y/(x^2+y^2+1) \\
w(x,y) = (x^2+y^2)/(x^2+y^2+1) \\$$

we can find inverses: 
$$
x(u,v,w) = u/(1-w)\\
y(u,v,w) = v/(1-w)\\
$$
Which means that from 
$$ f:R^2 -> R^3$$
 we have inverse function 
$$F: R^3-> R^2$$ 
Here it is easy to find these functions, but is there a general theorem that shows us when can we find inverse function from $R^n$ to $R^m$ and how to find it?

Comment: this is standard stereographic projection between the sphere $S^2$ minus the north pole and the plane. You can do the same thing between $S^n \subseteq R^{n+1}$ and $R^n.$

Comment: Your mapping $F$ is not defined on all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, e.g. not at $w=1$.

Comment: No continuous function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^3$ has an inverse function.  What you have is a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to the sphere
$\{(u,v,w): u^2+v^2+(w-1/2)^2 = 1/4\}$ with the point $(0,0,1)$ removed.

Comment: Yes, what I meant is not from $R^2$ to $R^3$ but from a subset of $R^n$ to a subset of $R^m$, like we have here. I am not asking about the example, I know what the Riemann sphere is, but for the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

In general, inverting a rational mapping from $\mathbb R^n$ to a subset of $\mathbb R^m$, even when it is possible, is not easy.  You might try [Gröbner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) techniques.